# Resume with the last image loaded

Tags: android

I have an array of image

```
private int[] q = {
        R.drawable.q1,R.drawable.q1,R.drawable.q2,R.drawable.q3,...
};
```

The app displays one image at a time, and change the image on button click

```
rand = rand + 1;
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(q[rand]);
```

What I need: when the user exits the app, the last image shown will be the first image to be shown when he re-open the app (or continue where the user left).

Example, I closed the app and the current image src is q[3] (or R.drawable.q2), and when I re-open the app, the image src should also be q[3].

Comment: Have you considered using SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

eg :

```
private SharedPreferences preference;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    preference = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(q[preference.getInt("intex", 0)]);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
    editor.putInt("intex", rand);
    editor.apply();
}
```